# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cv'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to use SVM with LeaveOneOut cross-validation (Loocv). The code is given below:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut, train_test_split
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

iRec = 'KSBPSSM_6_DCT_MIXED_49_937_937_1874_SMOTTMK.csv'
D = pd.read_csv(iRec, header=None)  # Using pandas

X = D.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = D.iloc[:, -1].values
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X, y = shuffle(X, y)  # Avoiding bias
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.75, 
test_size=0.25)

tpot = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=2.123, gamma=0.0039, cv=LeaveOneOut(), 
probability=True,)
tpot.fit(X_train, y_train)
print(tpot.score(X_test, y_test))
tpot.export('tpot_pipeline_'  + str(index) + '.py')
```

When I run the code, I received the folloing error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/PhD Folder/PhD research/DNA-binding Proteins literature 
papers/Effective DNA binding protein prediction by using key features via 
Chou’s general PseAAC_Code_dataset_10_10_2018/DNA_Binding- 
master/SVM_jackknife_test.py", line 18, in <module>
tpot = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=2.123, gamma=0.0039, cv=LeaveOneOut(), 
probability=True,)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cv'
```

Can anybody help me

Comment: Looking at the SVC documentation. the parameter 'cv' does not exist. were you looking for the 'decision_function_shape' parameter?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at [SVC documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) and [Cross-Validation Documentation (sklearn)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html0).

`SVC()` does not take any `cv` parameter, as a matter off fact, models don't take cross-validation into account. CV is used to check performance and prevent overfitting.

The example used in cross-validation documentation is actually with `SVC`.

In your case you could use [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score) as follows:

```
tpot = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=2.123, gamma=0.0039, probability=True)
scores = cross_val_score(tpot, X_test, y_test, cv=LeaveOneOut())
print(scores.mean())
```

Comment: I modified my code as suggested: tpot = SVC(kernel='rbf', C=2.123, gamma=0.0039, probability=True)
scores=cross_val_score(tpot, X_test, y_test, cv=LeaveOneOut())
print(score.mean())   I get the following error:  score=cross_val_score(tpot, X_test, y_test, cv=LeaveOneOut())
NameError: name 'cross_val_score' is not defined

Comment: @FarmanAli You need to import it: `from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score`